# Ubuntu consumes battery and warms laptop

Tags: battery

I have Ubuntu 12.10 (12.04 and upgraded to 12.10).
After upgrading I deleted old graphic drivers and instal FGLRX (or smth similar) to get graphic interface.

But after upgrade, battery consumption is high (it last about 90min, and before easily up to 4 hours) and laptop is warming up ( it feels hot under it, and area where asdfg buttons are).

Also, in system settings under graphics it's : Intel® Sandybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2
Laptop is Lenovo ThinkPad E520.

Is there any way to correct this? Laptop have dual graphics (Intel and ATI), and it would be nice to switch it somehow or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. Problem was with ATI drivers (AMD Catalyst™ 12.10 Proprietary Linux x86 Display Driver I tried). Its not compatible with xorg 1.13 which is in 12.10. 
So there is 3 options

1) Disable ATI Graphics (from BIOS or some other way in Linux)

2) Install ATI Legacy Drivers

3) Downgrade xorg from 1.13 to 1.12

I decided to go with option 1, because I want good look on Ubuntu (Gnome 3.6 and its perks).

But I saw that ATI has some beta drivers they are working on so I hope that driver will work.